# Remove MS Office

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office

Suddenly I found that my MS Word doesn't start. It just shows the message "Preparing to update Office..." in my native language. I was trying to remove office via Add/Remove programs but got the same issue. How to delete Office from my computer or make run an existing one?

Comment: You can repair the install of MS Office by selecting it via the Control Panel [Programs and Features] or Settings [Apps], choosing Change/Modify, and selecting the repair option _(offline first, and if it doesn't resolve, online)_; if that doesn't work, use @John's answer to remove and reinstall.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the Microsoft uninstall tool to remove Office when uninstall using Programs and Features does not work.

[Uninstall Office](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/uninstall-office-from-a-pc-9dd49b83-264a-477a-8fcc-2fdf5dbf61d8#:%7E:text=Click%20Start%20%3E%20Control%20Panel.,remove%2C%20and%20then%20click%20Uninstall.)

Here is the excerpt of the steps involved. You need to download the Uninstall Support Tool to uninstall Office.

[image: Remove Office]